# Beta function proof

Tags: proof-writing, special-functions

Show that : $$\beta \left( x,n\right) =\dfrac {\left( n-1\right) !}{x\left( x+1\right) \left( x+2\right) ....\left( x+n-1\right) }$$

My attempt : $$\beta \left( x,n\right) =\dfrac {\Gamma \left( x\right) \Gamma \left( n\right) }{\Gamma \left( x+n\right) }$$

$$\Gamma \left( n\right) =\left( n-1\right) !$$

Comment: So far so good. Now show that $$\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x+n)} = \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)\dotsc (x+n-1)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\beta(x,n)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt$$
so by an integration by parts we find
$$\beta(x,n)=(n-1)\frac1x\int_0^1 t^x(1-t)^{n-2}dt=\frac{n-1}x \beta(x+1,n-1)$$
Now a simple induction gives the desired result.

**Remark** In the induction you reach to:
$$\beta(x+n-1,1)=\int_0^1 t^{x+n-2}dt=\frac{1}{x+n-1}$$